# Compare two PySpark dataframes and modify one of them?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I can't find a Sparkified-way to do this, and was hoping some of you data experts out there might be able to help:

I have two dataframes:

1

```
item_list
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,0]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0]
```

2

```
item_list
[3,0,0,4,2,6,1,0,0]
```

I want to return a new dataframe like this. For every non-zero in DF 2, replace it with 1 if DF 1 is non-zero at that index and return a new dataframe.

Result:

```
item_list
[3,1,1,4,2,6,1,1,0]
```

This is fairly easy to do in standard python. How can I do this in Spark?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are using spark it doesn't necessarily mean you have to use only spark methods and process to work around.

I would suggest analyzing a problem and look through the best approachable solution. Since you are using PySpark and you have two lists, you can actually achieve this using python (as you mentioned) easily over spark and it might be the more ideal way to do it in the current scenario.

Spark comes into play when you think a language either pyhton or scala cannot achieve or may achieve but Spark can have some helping libraries which makes your life easy.

Comment: I would need to bring both dataframes into memory to do this with Python and they can get very large. Doing this in Python is not a scalable option.

Comment: However if you want to get a list of values from a dataframe you still need to get them into memory by doing collect() or any toher approach